# How can I copy a apache web server response variable to a new response header variable

Tags: apache, http-headers, response

I have a requirement where I would like a response variable to be copied to a new header variable.
i.e. a response variable called "Location" and to be copied to "X-Location".
From apache documentation I can see that I can set new headers or edit existing headers but I cannot seem to be able to copy a existing header to another header. I am using apache 2.2 .
Any pointers ?

Thanks
Narsimha

Comment: maybe `setenvif`? something like `setenvif ^Location ... yourvar=$1`, then `setenv x-location %yourvar`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
Header set X-Location "expr=%{resp:Location}"
```

This will copy response header `Location` to response header `X-Location`

Comment: But this needs apache 2.4.10 + https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#page-header